# webpack-dev "Cannot GET"

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm using webpack 5, when I start webpack-dev-server (i.e. using npm start) and hot reloading, I am getting **Cannot Get /** error.

what am I missing ?

It could be a routing problem too. There are no errors in webpacks output on the console.

I have the following webpack config:

webpack.common.js

```
const path = require("path");
const Dotenv = require("dotenv-webpack");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    bundle: path.resolve(__dirname, "/src/index.js"),
  },
  output: {
    filename: "index.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false,
    maxEntrypointSize: 512000,
    maxAssetSize: 512000,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.?js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.woff2?$/i,
        type: "asset/resource",
        dependency: { not: ["url"] },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      favicon: "./public/favicon.ico",
      template: path.join(__dirname, "public", "index.html"),
      manifest: "./public/manifest.json",
    }),
    new Dotenv(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
  ],
};
```

webpack.dev.js

```
const { merge } = require("webpack-merge");
const path = require("path");
const common = require("./webpack.common.js");

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: "development",
  devtool: "inline-source-map",
  devServer: {
    static: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  },
});
```

webpack.prod.js

```
const { merge } = require("webpack-merge");
const common = require("./webpack.common.js");

module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: "production",
  devtool: "source-map",
});
```

scripts:

```
"start": "webpack serve --open --config webpack.dev.js",
"build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js"
```